# VueJS/Nuxt: this.$router.push returning different (wrong) template to <nuxt-link>

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, nuxt.js

I am working on a search component which takes the value of a select box, and redirects the user to an appropriate page. However I have noticed that when the page renders, it is calling the wrong template and as a result does not show the content.

Navigating via `<nuxt-link>` does return the correct template.

I want the `$router.push` to render the same template as `<nuxt-link>`. How do I make that happen?

Relevant code below...

**Template**

```
<template>
    <section class="search" role="search" aria-label="Search">
        <div class="form-group" v-if="searchReady">
            <span class="option-group">
                <label for="visitortype">I am a</label>
                <select v-model="visitor" :searchable="false" :onChange="getData(visitor)">
                    <option v-for="(v, index) in typesVisitor" :key="index">{{ v.name }}</option>
                </select>
            </span>
            <span class="option-group">
                <label for="experiencetype">looking for</label>
                <select label="name" v-model="experience.name" :searchable="false" :onChange="setExperience(experience)">
                    <option v-for="(x, index) in typesExperience" :key="index">{{ x.name }}</option>
                </select>
            </span>
        </div>
        <button class="button" @click="loadExperience">Show Me</button>
    </section>
</template>
```

**Script**

```
loadExperience() {
    // Redirect to experience page (e.g. '/dir/page')
    this.$router.push(this.searchDestination);
}
```

Comment: There might be some issue with router where you are defining your component, will it be possible to reproduce on codesandbox so i can investigate more ?

Comment: It works fine via `<nuxt-link>` though - so I don't see how the route is the issue. I think it is more likely my implementation of the router. This is part of a large application, and it's difficult to separate it out, sorry.

Comment: can you paste the nuxt-link code ?

And what is the value of searchDestination ?

Comment: I have noticed in the Vue Dev Tools that the real page router-view is set to `/activites/:slug`, but when triggered by the search component the router view returns `/:slug`

Comment: @MohitBajoria The nuxt like is as `<nuxt-link to="/activities/adventure"><p>Adventure</p></nuxt-link>` and the value of `searchDestination` is `/activities/adventure` - I think I may need to include some params in route, maybe?

Comment: I think push is not same with nuxt-link , eg. if current url is `/user/1` nuxt-link will go like `/activities/adventure` while push will go like `/user/1/activities/adventure` . Just use location.href

Comment: @DavidJawHpan The URL resolves correctly though, it just renders the wrong template (standard page instead of listing page) which is why I think I may need to pass some additional parameters for it to be able to figure everything out.

Comment: how about trying with location.href ! Is it the same ?

Comment: @DavidJawHpan I've updated it to use `location.href` and some destinations work, others don't. Very strange.

Comment: @DavidJawHpan Don't mind me - my default path for the first option was incorrect. So, having fixed that and tried both `push` and `location.href` - they both work.

Answer (score 0):

So, it turns out my data feed had incorrect information in it, which is why the wrong template was being loaded. VueJS/Nuxt been clever enough to create pages without content based on routes had me confused.

For the record though, both `this.$route.push` and `window.location.href` worked equally well.

Sorry everyone who tried to help, I appreciate you getting me to the solution, however indirectly!